# Flask: how to ignore new requests if last one is not done yet

Tags: python, rest, api, http, flask

I am trying to build REST API with only one call.

Sometimes it takes up to 30 seconds for a program to return a response. But if user thinks that service is lagging - he makes a new call and my app returns response with error code 500 (Internal Server Error).

For now it is enough for me to block any new requests if last one is not ready. Is there any simple way to do it?

I know that there is a lot of queueing managers like Celery, but I prefer not to overload my app with any large dependencies/etc.

Comment: Define "block". What would you expect the user to receive as a response if they're trying to make a new request while the last one was not done yet?

Comment: Maybe user should receive some information that job is not done yet. And wait for a last response. Because now new request leads to an error and because of that correct last response doesn't appears. Or is it a problem for a front-end client - he should make a checking if the response is an error or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **Flask-Limiter** to ignore new requests from that remote address.
`pip install Flask-Limiter`
Check this quickstart:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address

app = Flask(__name__)
limiter = Limiter(
    app,
    key_func=get_remote_address,
    default_limits=["200 per day", "50 per hour"]
)
@app.route("/slow")
@limiter.limit("1 per day")
def slow():
    return "24"

@app.route("/fast")
def fast():
    return "42"

@app.route("/ping")
@limiter.exempt
def ping():
    return "PONG"
```

As you can see, you could ignore the remote IP address for a certain amount of time meanwhile you finish the process you´re running

### DOCS

Check these two links:

- [Flasf-Limiter Documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/flask-limiter/latest/flask-limiter.pdf)
- [Flasf-Limiter Quick start](https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: This is nice. It helps to block new requests. But how to make it return response for the previous request?

Comment: The code from the previous request should be running without being interrupted by the newer request because they run separately, so the old one should keep returning its response

Comment: Yes, checked it. Thanks, this is exactly what I need.